# SQL Server 2005 SP3 Failover Cluster Node Replacement Service Pack

Tags: sql-server-2005, cluster, 64-bit, windows-server-2003-r2

2-node SQL Server 2005 SP3 (9.0.4226) Failover Cluster running on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 SP2. My passive node suffered a RAID failure on the OS partition. I evicted the failed node, rebuilt it, rejoined it to the cluster, and run SQL setup from the active node to to reinstall SQL Server onto the passive node.

I am at the point where I need to update the passive node's SQL binaries to match the active node's. I also need to upgrade this cluster to SQL Server 2005 SP4.

My question: can I just run SP4 on the active cluster node and have it update the binaries on the inactive node (rather than bringing the inactive node up to 9.0.4226 first, then running SP4)?

I'd like to keep my downtime short, so only having to run 1 service pack is preferred. I haven't been able to find documentation which says I can or can't (or shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

[According to Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7218):

> Service Pack 4 (SP4) for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 is now available
>   for download. SQL Server 2005 service packs are cumulative, and this
>   service pack upgrades all service levels of SQL Server 2005 to SP4 .

Comment: Right, SPs are cumulative, so in theory it shouldn't matter what version the binaries on the passive node are at, as they will be fully updated to SP4. I will give it a go.